# Want to uninstall SQL Server Visual Studio

Tags: sql, database, oracle, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have installed Oracle DBMS in my system. I already have SQL Server and Visual Studio on my system. Now I want to install SQL Server and Visual Studio. I want to ask how can I safely remove both these software packages without affecting Oracle? I don't want to mess up with Oracle database.

Comment: I don't think the installations of these different software systems will affect each other.

Comment: At least the shouldn't interfere :).